# O método show() no meu wpf não funciona

Tags: c#, wpf

Fiz uma pequeníssima aplicação desktop usando wpf. Tenho uma tela de login bem simples mesmo e nessa tela deveria chamar a tela principal. Fiz assim:

```
Menu menu = new Menu();
menu.Show();
```

Está dando erro no show, dizendo que não é reconhecido. O namespace `System.Windows` está adicionado ao projeto.

Comment: Qual é o erro **exatamente**?

Comment: @LINQ, diz que Menu não contém uma definição para Show(). Será que preciso adicionar algum assembly?

Comment: Menu é de qual namespace? Se for da `System.Windows.Controls` este método **não existe** e nem faria sentido existir.

Comment: @LINQ, Menu é uma classe que eu criei e é ela que eu quero mostrar.

Comment: Acho que foi o nome da classe Menu que eu criei e coincidiu com algum nome reservado. Criei uma noca classe com outro nome e funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que a classe `Menu` do seu código se refere a classe [`System.Windows.Controls.Menu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menu(v=vs.110).aspx).

Escreva o nome completo da sua classe `Menu` ou defina um *alias* para o seu namespace (ou para o `System.Windows.Controls`). O importante é remover a ambiguidade.

```
var menu = new SeuNamespace.Menu();
menu.Show();
```